# How do I detect or handle after a 3rd party plugin finishes its post request in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I am using WordPress with WooCommerce. We have a 3rd party payment plugin installed  to handle the payments.

The 3rd party plugin inserts an `<iframe></iframe>` dynamically with its "Place Order" button inside the `html element` of the iframe

```
<iframe src="https://checkout-eu.playground.klarna.com/12345/checkout.html#%7B%22ORDER_URL%22%25">
  <html>
    <body>
      <button>Place Order</button>
    </body>
  </html>
</iframe>
```

The "Place Order" button sends a post request to an external url that looks similar to this https://checkout-eu.playground.klarna.com/yaco/orders/any_hash

Do you know how can I detect if the `POST request` is done via jQuery? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

My reason to detect is to stop redirecting the page after the POST request is done then show the receipt on the same page only

Comment: Any specific reason for detecting the `POST` request is done via jQuery.

Comment: my reason is to stop redirecting the page after the POST request is done then show the receipt on the same page only..

Comment: Technically you can't do this until klarna.com permit cross-origin framing.

Comment: That you cannot do by intercepting like this. You have to see the documentation of api itself whether they provide any callback function or not